# Cakephp 2.1 encrypt and decrypt a string

Tags: cakephp-2.1, encryption

I'm using Cakephp 2.1.

How can I encrypt and decrypt a string.

Comment: You should really provide more details about what you want to do: what kind of string do you want encrypted and why, what kind of encryption? There's more than one kind of it... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption

Answer (score 1):

As per CakePHP [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/security.html):

Encrypt your secret password with my_key

`$secret = Security::cipher('my secret password', 'my_key');`

Later decrypt your secret password

`$nosecret = Security::cipher($secret, 'my_key');`